# Android Lifecycle ViewModel not persisted after locking and unlocking in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle, android-architecture

I have a pretty simple app with a dummy `Activity` and dummy Android Lifecycle ViewModel `ViewModel`.

**FragmentActivity**

```
class FragmentActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "FragmentActivity"
        private const val KEY = "key_key"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment)
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onCreate: orientation ${resources.configuration.orientation}")

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onCreate: saved string from savedInstanceState ${savedInstanceState.getString(KEY)}")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onCreate: no savedInstanceState")
        }

        val myViewModel: MyViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, VmFactory())
                .get(MyViewModel::class.java)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onResume: orientation ${resources.configuration.orientation}")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onStop: orientation ${resources.configuration.orientation}")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onDestroy: orientation ${resources.configuration.orientation}")
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        val savedString = "SAVED_STATE_" + hashCode()
        outState?.putString(KEY, savedString)
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity ${hashCode()}, onSaveInstanceState: $savedString")

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MyViewModel"
    }

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyViewModel ${hashCode()}: created")
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyViewModel ${hashCode()}: onCleared")

        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

**ViewModelFactory**

```
class VmFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass == MyViewModel::class.java) {
            return MyViewModel() as T
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dkarmazi.unknownmemorysampleapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FragmentActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Steps to kill the ViewModel**

1. Put the app to landscape mode
2. Lock the screen
3. Unlock the screen and observe that ViewModel is gone, Activity destroyed and created two times.

**Log output**

```
02-20 16:30:14.159 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onCreate: orientation 2
02-20 16:30:14.159 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onCreate: no savedInstanceState
02-20 16:30:14.169 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/MyViewModel: MyViewModel 55090662: created
02-20 16:30:14.183 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onResume: orientation 2
### LOCKED IN LANDSCAPE MODE
02-20 16:30:22.978 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onSaveInstanceState: SAVED_STATE_244798673
02-20 16:30:22.996 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onStop: orientation 2
### UNLOCKED IN LANDSCAPE MODE
02-20 16:30:33.177 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onStop: orientation 2
02-20 16:30:33.178 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/MyViewModel: MyViewModel 55090662: onCleared
02-20 16:30:33.179 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onDestroy: orientation 2
02-20 16:30:33.241 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onCreate: orientation 1
02-20 16:30:33.241 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onCreate: saved string from savedInstanceState SAVED_STATE_244798673
02-20 16:30:33.242 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/MyViewModel: MyViewModel 113479034: created
02-20 16:30:33.248 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onResume: orientation 1
02-20 16:30:33.705 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onSaveInstanceState: SAVED_STATE_218111434
02-20 16:30:33.710 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onStop: orientation 1
02-20 16:30:33.712 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 218111434, onDestroy: orientation 1
02-20 16:30:33.815 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 158140230, onCreate: orientation 2
02-20 16:30:33.815 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 158140230, onCreate: saved string from savedInstanceState SAVED_STATE_218111434
02-20 16:30:33.822 8296-8296/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 158140230, onResume: orientation 2
```

This behavior is consistent with findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205049/android-activity-lifecycle-and-locking-unlocking-device), however, I'd expect the arch library to handle this case as it is pretty standard and locking and unlocking in portrait mode works as expected.

Any good ideas on preventing that `ViewModel` from being destroyed in this particular scenario?

Tested on Nexus 5X, API 27

**EDIT 1:** after adding a string to be saved in `onSaveInstanceState` and checking if that string persists through all activity destroys and creates, I'm pretty sure that this is a bug with the library.

**EDIT 2:** Why is this a problem?

Problem 1: In case of landscape locking, the bundle gets somehow properly routed from Activity 244798673 to Activity 218111434 at `02-20 16:30:33.241`, however the `ViewModel` is not able to persist through this sequence of actions. This is inconsistent with bundles behavior as we're technically still within the same Activity scope.

Problem 2: Log output for locking and unlocking in portrait mode:

```
02-20 16:38:10.283 8567-8567/? D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onCreate: orientation 1
02-20 16:38:10.283 8567-8567/? D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onCreate: no savedInstanceState
02-20 16:38:10.293 8567-8567/? D/MyViewModel: MyViewModel 55090662: created
02-20 16:38:10.301 8567-8567/? D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onResume: orientation 1
02-20 16:38:13.459 8567-8567/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onSaveInstanceState: SAVED_STATE_244798673
02-20 16:38:13.480 8567-8567/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onStop: orientation 1
02-20 16:38:17.704 8567-8567/com.dkarmazi.viewmodelscoping D/FragmentActivity: Activity 244798673, onResume: orientation 1
```

`ViewModel` is persisted in portrait locking and unlocking which is  inconsistent with landscape scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug that originates from Android framework:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644080

Android Arch Library under the hood uses retained fragments in order to persist `ViewModels`. Experimentally, in the same scenario of locking and unlocking the device in landscape mode when PIN / PATTERN / SWIPE / PASSWORD is turned on, retained fragments won't be able to survive it either. Therefore, each time we unlock the device, we will be getting a new instance of a `ViewModel`.

Some use cases:

1. Device: NEXUS 5X, API level: 24, lock method: PIN / PATTERN / SWIPE / PASSWORD. Can reproduce by unlocking with any of the unlocking methods. Can also reproduce by unlocking with fingerprint.
2. Device: NEXUS 5X, API level: 27, lock method: PIN / PATTERN / PASSWORD . Can reproduce only when unlocking the device with a fingerprint. Unlocking with PIN / PATTERN / PASSWORD works fine.
3. Device: Pixel, API level: 27, lock method: PIN (haven't tested other) + fingerprint. Can reproduce only when unlocking the device with a fingerprint. Unlocking with PIN / PATTERN / PASSWORD works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModelFactory you provide here is not the Singleton. That should be the issue.

```
val myViewModel: MyViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, VmFactory())
                .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Make the factory to singleton, it should work.

Comment: Nope, it will not help, if you look at the source code for `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider::get()` will call `Factory::create` only if it could not retrieve the existing view model internally. Scope of the factory doesn't really matter in this case, `Factory::create` will be called regardless if it's a singleton or not.

Comment: See the source below. If you provide your own factory, it uses the provided one else it uses a static instance of default factory(sDefaultFactory variable). https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.java.